# sleep function not working as expected nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

hello i am writing a nodejs function that send requests in using array.map but i want to make the function wait or sleep during 4min when there is an error before sending the next request ,i have tried to use sleep but the map function doesnt wait 4 min  before sending the next request:

here is the map function :
  `data.Item.json.map(( id, index ) =>   setTimeout(()=>  activityService.streamActivity(id),(5+index) * 6000))`

and there is the called function inside the map :`

```
const streamActivity = (client) => (activityId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        client.streams.activity(
            {
                id: activityId,
                types:
                    "time,heartrate,velocity_smooth,altitude,distance,latlng,cadence,watts,temp,moving,grade_smooth,average_speed",
                resolution: "high",
            },
            async function (err, payload,next) {



             
                if (!err ) {

                    //save to dynamodb


                    var params = {
                        TableName: "streams",
                        Item: {
                            "id":activityId,
                            "json": payload,
                        }
                    };

                    docClient.put(params, function(err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("Unable to add movie",  ". Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                        } else {
                            console.log("PutItem succeeded:" +activityId);
                        }
                    });


                } else {
                   
                     await sleep(60000)
                }
            }
        );
    });
     // setInterval(streamActivity,5000);

};
```

`

Comment: Inside `.map()`? You can't await inside a map. You have to use a `for` loop if you want to await in it

Comment: As written, `streamActivity()` is a function that returns a function (a socalled factory) but it is not called as such.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop instead of `.map()` to loop through the array.

```js
for (const [index, id] of data.Item.json.entries()) {
  setTimeout(() => activityService.streamActivity(id), (5 + index) * 6000);
}
```